# Is there a difference between WAS and AppFabric

Tags: .net, wcf, was, appfabric

I understand that AppFabric has both caching capabilities along with hosting WCF/WF services. I have seen Windows Activation Service used interchangeably with AppFabric when talking about hosting services on IIS 7.0

Are both one and the same?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not. AppFabric is built on top of the WAS facilities, but adds a lot more things including better monitoring and configuration tools, good Workflow Services hosting, tracking and reporting for persistent services/workflows and a few more things.